# Why do I need .NET 3.5 to install .NET 3.5?

Tags: installation, .net-framework, .net-3.5

EDIT: **Please read what I have already tried before commenting/answering. Thank you.**

I just found a completely ridiculous problem. I have Win10 on my laptop. It comes with .NET 4.5 installed but not 3.5. I want to run a game that uses 3.5 (it won't run without it). When I run either the online or offline .NET 3.5 installer, it says I need .NET 3.5 to install .NET 3.5!

[image: Ridiculous error is ridiculous]

This is extremely frustrating. Is there a way I can manually install it?

---

Things I have tried:

- Running the .NET 3.5 Online Installer (2Mb)
- Running the .NET 3.5 Offline Installer (237Mb)
- Using dism.exe as per Method 3 listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2734782) (it says `The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.`)
- Running the .NET Verification Tool.
- Refreshing my Windows (it fails and says nothing has changed)
- Troubleshooting the installer (it says `Incompatible program`, which is wrong because I have .NET 4.5 installed)
- Installing .NET 2.0 (apparently I need .NET 3.5 for that too)

None of these work! Any ideas?

Comment: Hit "install this feature"

Comment: @Ramhound It says `The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.` when I click that too.

Comment: You have tried installing it through the add windows feature?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried adding it through Windows Features but it fails saying `The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.`...

Comment: You don't need to install .Net framework 3.5 in Windows 10 as it is built in to it already. If enabling it failed for you, you can try [DISM method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482069.aspx)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I already said, .NET 3.5 isn't installed for me and I already tried the `dism` command. It says `The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.`.

Comment: Sounds like you may have file system corruption.  Run a `CHKDSK`, then run an `SFC /Scannow`, and if/after those report no problem found (and/or all problems fixed), try it again.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 `Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.`

Comment: That tells you that you have corrupt Windows files.. And the repository is also corrupt.  Fix that and your .Net install problem should be fixed.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 And how exactly do I fix these corrupt files? My CBS.log is [here](https://mega.nz/#!nkFjCLTJ!S1i-sVOhY1QK_yBh6vMzF8zTde7ARRBMRKAEfeE9l80) if that helps.

Comment: Is it checked in `Turn Windows features on or off` within `Programs and Features`?

Comment: @ssnobody It's off but I can't turn it on because it says `The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.`

Comment: When this happens, you normally have to do a repair installation of windows. You put in the install disk to run Windows, and watch for the option to do a repair install instead of a normal install. With the Windows 10 upgrade, I'm not sure where you'll be able to go to get that disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to fix this is to redownload the Windows 10 Installation Media and install Win10 from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error recently. In my case "Windows Update" was not enabled, but similar to Windows IME, Windows Update seems to be required to fetch .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

To install .NET 3.5 on Windows 10, you need to use Windows Features, and specify the Windows 10 installation source (i.e., the DVD or USB you used to install Windows 10). I use this command most of the time (from an elevated command prompt):

`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /all /source:d:\sources\sxs`

Substitute `d:\` for your DVD or USB drive, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I already said this didn't work in my list of things I had tried. It says `The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.`.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen that in the original post, only that you jad tried the GUI. :-(

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.5 should already be included with the installation of Windows 10. You can enable it in Windows Features. Try following the steps in [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10)